# Can't import ".html" file in Typescript using Parcel

Tags: typescript, parceljs

I'm trying to setup a simple project using Typescript and [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/).

Within this project, I'm trying to import a `.html` file (or, more accurately, its path) from a `.ts`:

```js
import html from "../renderer/index.html";
console.log(html); // file:///home/foo/bar/dist/main/renderer.1c7e1d82.html
```

As mentioned in several places, in order for this to work I added the following declaration file `html.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '*.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value
}
```

And my full `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main/main.ts"
    ],
    "include": ["@types"]
}
```

The configuration appears to be correct, as my IDE seems to recognise the import above, and running `tsc` doesn't fail and yields the expected result (`require("../renderer/index.html")`).

However, when trying to bundle with Parcel (`parcel build main.ts`). While the compilation itself works as expected, with the import being substituted by `new URL("renderer.1c7e1d82.html", "file:" + __filename).toString();` It fails to recognise the `d.ts` file, as the following warning is thrown:

```
@parcel/transformer-typescript-types: Cannot find module '../renderer/index.html' or its corresponding type declarations.

  /home/angrykoala/Desktop/scratchpad/gaucho2/src/main/main.ts:9:18
     8 | 
  >  9 | import html from "../renderer/index.html";
  >    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Cannot find module '../renderer/index.html' or its corresponding type declarations.
    10 | console.log(html)
    11 |
```

As per the documentation, my `.pretierrc` is set to use `tsc`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc"]
  }
}
```

And yet, it fails to take into account `files` or `include` parameters from tsconfig. Any other permutation I've tried (such as removing files) had the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parcel string inlining is done using `bundle-text:` prefix.

```js
import html from "bundle-text:../renderer/index.html";
```

Parcel automatically adds devDependency `@parcel/transformer-inline-string`.

More at https://parceljs.org/features/bundle-inlining.

I usually create a definition file `global.d.ts` which includes:

```js
declare module "bundle-text:*" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

And add line `includes: ["**/*.ts"]` to `tsconfig.json`.

EDIT:
More about `tsconfig` `includes` at https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include.
Note it's important to include the definition file as well which is covered by pattern `"**/*.ts"`.